# If any of the value in that set is equal to x, then select that set of values

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's a sample:

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
value<-c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
sample<-data.frame(id,value)
```

In this example, `id`=1 has 5 values, and `id`=2 also has 5. I want to select **all of the values** that belong to an `id` if **any value** equals 1. Therefore, in this example, all values of `id`=1 will be selected. How do I do this with `dplyr`?

Comment: `cbind()` creates a matrix, I assume you want a data frame so use `data.frame()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
sample |> 
  group_by(id) |>
  filter(1 %in% value)
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
# # Groups:   id [1]
#      id value
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     0
# 2     1     0
# 3     1     0
# 4     1     0
# 5     1     1
```

Alternately

```
sample |> 
  group_by(id) |>
  filter(any(value == 1))
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
# # Groups:   id [1]
#      id value
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     0
# 2     1     0
# 3     1     0
# 4     1     0
# 5     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R` with `subset`

```
subset(sample, id %in% id[as.logical(value)])
```

-output

```
   id value
1  1     0
2  1     0
3  1     0
4  1     0
5  1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset` + `ave` (if we don't specify `FUN` in `ave`, we calculate `mean` by default)

```
> subset(sample, ave(value, id) > 0)
  id value
1  1     0
2  1     0
3  1     0
4  1     0
5  1     1
```